# Can not startup the Oracle 12.2 on Linux with errors: ORA-01012 and then ORA-24454

Tags: linux, oracle, startup

I restarted the oracle installation server, and then oracle stopped working. I tried to use terminal and sqlplus to execute command "startup" but got the error ORA-01012 (not logged on), I searched the internet for information and tried to get it done using the syntax: "sysresv" to list shared memories, then use "ipcrm -m" command to remove them.
However, after continuing to execute the startup command, and no more error ORA-01012, the error ORA-24454 (client host name is not set) reappears. At present, I am very confused, do not know how to do to reboot the data system. Please help me find the solution!

Comment: Make sure you have set the environment before sqlplus login. 1. sudo su - oracle, 2. source .oraenv (input SID) 3. env | grep ORA 4. sqlplus / as sysdba 5. SQL>startup

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you explain more carefully? I have never used the linux operating system before, I have just been communicating with the system and am very confused!

Comment: I tried to follow the steps you pointed out, but still got the same error!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error and successfully booted the database system.
An error is very simple, but due to inattention it becomes complicated. The reason is that because the hostname is set incorrectly, I fixed the hostname with the command:

```
hostname <new name>
```

and also edited in the host file: declare the new ip address and hostname

```
/etc/host
```